# UIViewController under bottom bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, toolbar

My ViewController is embed in a UINavigationController. I have a translucent bottom bar (toolbar), and I want my ViewController to expand under the toolbar.

I checked `Under Bottom Bars` in Storyboard, in both the UINavigationController and the ViewController. But the ViewController still don't extend under bottom bar.

Any Ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behavior. If the `UIViewController`'s view would extend below the bottom bar, that portion would be inaccessible to the user. I suggest you add a semi-transparent view to the bottom instead of the default bar, in your case.

Comment: Ok, so what is the purpose of the "Extend under bottom bars" option in IB ?

Comment: Didn't know about that option

Comment: Check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html)